# Is there active research in Galois Theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, galois-theory

I recently decided to introduce myself to the field of Modern Algebra - in particular, Galois theory - and I found it absolutely beautiful! Thus I would really like to study something in Galois theory, which leads me to ask - do people still develop Galois theory? What else is there to learn in the subject?

I am inspired by questions like these:
[What kind of work do modern day algebraists do?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181220/what-kind-of-work-do-modern-day-algebraists-do) and [What do modern-day analysts actually do?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/what-do-modern-day-analysts-actually-do/154967) and would love to learn your opinions, stories, etc!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is a very active research area that can be approached via combinatorics, number theory, representation theory or algebraic geometry. Some classical problems like the inverse Galois problem over $\mathbb Q$ are still unresolved.

Comment: Yes, there is active research. There are still lots of open questions about the inverse Galois problem. I know one person who recently started a research in probabilistic Galois theory. (which deals with stuff like distribution of polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with Galois group $S_n$ and more such questions). Don't really know the details though.

Comment: you can look up the description of the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem and see that Galois theory was used in it, iirc.

Answer (score 42):

I'm going to give a short, very simplified overview of something that I'm somewhat familiar with, though there are many other open streams in research that I don't have the experience to comment on.

Let $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ denote the absolute Galois group, i.e. the group of all field automorphisms $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\to\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ fixing the rationals. Equivalently, $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is the inverse limit of Galois groups $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ of finite Galois extensions $L/\mathbb{Q}$, so in a certain sense it is made up of all finite Galois groups over $\mathbb Q$.

Perhaps the most well-known open problem in Galois theory is

> What is the structure of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$?

An approach to this problem is through the famous [Langlands program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program). A different approach was outlined by Grothendieck in his, also relatively well known, [Esquisse d'un programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquisse_d%27un_Programme).

There Grothendieck notes that $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ has a faithful action on the collection of graphs embedded on compact surfaces, which he calls *dessins d'enfants* (children's drawings) due to their apparent simplicity. If one can understand this action, then in principle one can represent the elements of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ as permutations of dessins d'enfants. Thus one of the main open problems of the theory of dessins d'enfants is to

> Classify enough invariants of dessins d'enfants so that any two orbits of the action of  $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ can be distinguished.

Shortly after Grothendieck's Esquisse went into circulation, Drinfeld proved that $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ injects into the so-called *Grothendieck-Teichmuller group*, which has an explicit description in terms of generators and relations. Hence one other open problem is

> Is $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group?

These are very difficult problems which raise further questions still unresolved, for example how can one compute a dessin d'enfant efficiently. Furthermore, theoretical physicists are also interested in Galois theory: Drinfeld's introduction of the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group was motivated by mathematical physics, and dessin d'enfants have already appeared in physics under a different name, dimer models.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The site definitely needs more users who have seen this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There are several generalizations of Galois Theory in progress. Some of them are of groups acting on commutative and non-commutative rings (other than fields), groups acting partially on rings, groupoids acting globally and partially on rings, and much more. We have a group of students and professors who work with that type of variants in my university (Federal University of Rio Grande do Sul - UFRGS). Some beautiful papers that you can look to know more about it (they are a little difficult, but are just examples of what you can do):

[Partial groupoid actions: globalization, Morita theory and Galois theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0670)

[The Galois correspondence theorem for groupoid actions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325207712_The_Galois_correspondence_theorem_for_groupoid_actions)

[Partial actions and Galois theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242983555_Partial_actions_and_Galois_theory)

[A Characterisation for a groupoid Galois extension using partial isomorphisms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314244376_A_CHARACTERISATION_for_A_GROUPOID_GALOIS_EXTENSION_USING_PARTIAL_ISOMORPHISMS)

[A Galois-Grothendieck-type correspondence for groupoid actions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259044602_A_Galois-Grothendieck-type_correspondence_for_groupoid_actions)

[Galois correspondences for partial Galois Azumaya extensions](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/%7Evirginia/PRS2.pdf)

Hope you enjoy it!